# Set Dialogue position over Google Map Android

Tags: android, google-maps, dialog, position, map-projections

I want to implement a view like Info Window above the clicked marker. info window is not useful for me, because I want to implement multiple buttons inside it. I am able to create dialog on marker click, also able to set its Gravity Eg: GRAVITY.TOP.

I am getting screen position in pixel from the projection of map. But unable to set the position of Dialog over map.

Here is My onMarkerClick method:

```
@Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Marker Clicked"+ arg0.getTitle());

        final Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        d.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
        d.setContentView(R.layout.info_window_layout);

        AppCompatImageView btnAction1 = d.findViewById(R.id.action1);

        AppCompatImageView btnAction2 = d.findViewById(R.id.action2);
        AppCompatImageView btnAction3 = d.findViewById(R.id.action3);

        final LatLng latlong = arg0.getPosition();

        Projection projection = mMap.getProjection();

        // Returns a screen location that corresponds to a geographical coordinate
        Point screenPosition = projection.toScreenLocation(latlong);

        Window window = d.getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
        wlp.x = screenPosition.x;
        wlp.y = screenPosition.y;

        wlp.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;

        wlp.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
        window.setAttributes(wlp);   

        d.show();
        return true;
    }
```

My info_window_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/action1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action1"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/action2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/action3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_actione3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the screenshot, what i get now!

[image: Screenshot]